# SIGSEGV when setting backgroundDrawable for each element in ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, listadapter, android-drawable

I want to set something I have drawn on canvas as background of each element displayed in `ListView`. The drawing depends on the contents of the element and must be on `Canvas`, that's why I can not set it from the laout xml of the ListView element. I need to use `View#setBackgroundDrawable`.

This works OK when done on single view element but I get very weird error when I try it in the `ListViewAdapter`. Here is the code of the `getView` method of my adapter:

```
public View getView(int position, View listRowView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (listRowView == null) {
        listRowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.slide_layout_row, null);
    }
    BackgroundDrawable drawable = BackgroundDrawable.getBackgroundDrawableFromCache(activity, list.get(position));
    listRowView.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
    return listRowView;
}
```

As you can see I tried avoiding possible out of memory problem using cache, but removing the cache does not change the end result. I have around 100 elements in my list view and if I try to run the application I get this weird piece of crap in the log cat:

```
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000004 (code=1), thread 20514 (android.widgets)
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** Build fingerprint: 'samsung/yakjuxw/maguro:4.2.1/JOP40D/I9250XWMA2:user/release-keys' Revision: '9' pid: 20514, tid: 20514, name: android.widgets  >>> com.cappucino.android.widgets <<< signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000004
    r0 bece0630  r1 400520a4  r2 40052008  r3 00000000
    r4 40052008  r5 00000001  r6 00000000  r7 40cd7a70
    r8 bece0670  r9 40cd7a68  sl 400dd020  fp bece0684
    ip 402522f5  sp bece0630  lr 40ab5d59  pc 40ab5c7c  cpsr 28000030
    d0  3f8000003f800000  d1  4434000000000000
    d2  4434000042480000  d3  0000000144940000
    d4  4411000000000000  d5  4411800044340000
    d6  00000003000000ff  d7  5da8eae800000013
    d8  0000000000000000  d9  0000000000000000
    d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
    d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
    d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
    d16 000000c14170b8f8  d17 000000c140e659a0
    d18 000000000196e158  d19 0000000000000000
    d20 400147b000000000  d21 40028f5c20000000
    d22 0000000000000000  d23 40028f5c20000000
    d24 3ff0000000000000  d25 0000000000000000
    d26 0000000000000000  d27 c038000000000000
    d28 0000000000000000  d29 3ff0000000000000
    d30 3ff0000000000000  d31 3ff0000000000000
    scr 60000090 backtrace:
    #00  pc 0001ac7c  /system/lib/libhwui.so
    #01  pc 0001ad55  /system/lib/libhwui.so
    #02  pc 0005b2ff  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
    #03  pc 0001e290  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+112)
    #04  pc 0004d411  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+396)
    #05  pc 000276e4  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    #06  pc 000207d8  [stack] stack:
         bece05f0  5c35bf08  
         bece05f4  5c35bf08  
         bece05f8  40e55828  [heap]
         bece05fc  2f40001d  
         bece0600  00000001  
         bece0604  bece0670  [stack]
         bece0608  40cd79d0  
         bece060c  400dd020  
         bece0610  bece0684  [stack]
         bece0614  407ed061  /system/lib/libdvm.so
         bece0618  c0000000  
         bece061c  00000000  
         bece0620  00000001  
         bece0624  5dca4348  
         bece0628  df0027ad  
         bece062c  00000000  
    #00  bece0630  00000029  
         bece0634  00000000  
         bece0638  40e59558  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
         bece063c  40e57ed8  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
         bece0640  5d99d7b0  
         bece0644  40052008  
         bece0648  00000001  
         bece064c  00000000  
         bece0650  40cd7a70  
         bece0654  40ab5d59  /system/lib/libhwui.so
    #01  bece0658  00000000  
         bece065c  40ab5d45  /system/lib/libhwui.so
         bece0660  400dd010  
         bece0664  40252301  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
    #02  bece0668  56d9b160  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-LinearAlloc (deleted)
         bece066c  407cf294  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+116) memory near r0:
    bece0610 bece0684 407ed061 c0000000 00000000  
    bece0620 00000001 5dca4348 df0027ad 00000000  
    bece0630 00000029 00000000 40e59558 40e57ed8  
    bece0640 5d99d7b0 40052008 00000001 00000000  
    bece0650 40cd7a70 40ab5d59 00000000 40ab5d45  
    bece0660 400dd010 40252301 56d9b160 407cf294  
    bece0670 40cd7a68 00000001 40e7eab8 00000008  
    bece0680 4170d90c 407fe415 40cd7a68 5895c109  
    bece0690 402522f5 400dd020 e0e00019 00000000  
    bece06a0 5dcadae8 40193228 40de2d88 40de2d88  
    bece06b0 c0000000 40de2d88 00000000 5dcada18  
    bece06c0 00000000 40159813 40de2d88 00000000  
    bece06d0 5dcada18 00000000 40de2d88 40154f15  
    bece06e0 40de2e1c 40812cc7 bece06fc 000000c1  
    bece06f0 40e7eab8 40de2e1c 00000000 00000000  
    bece0700 bece0760 5dcad9b0 40e659a0 000000c1   memory near r1:
    40052084 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
    40052094 3f800000 47200101 454f5f4c 40d4a8d0  
    400520a4 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
    400520b4 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
    400520c4 3f800000 00000000 3f800000 00000000  
    400520d4 00000000 3f800000 00000000 3f800000  
    400520e4 3f800000 3f800000 3f800000 3f800000  
    400520f4 47455f00 6d695f4c 20656761 4f5f4c47  
    40052104 455f5345 695f4c00 6567616d 7478655f  
    40052114 00000000 41400000 3f800000 00000000  
    40052124 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
    40052134 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
    40052144 ff000000 00000000 40800000 04000000  
    40052154 51321fc8 00000000 00000000 5dca4008  
    40052164 40ac6e98 00000000 00000000 00000007  
    40052174 00000004 40ac6ee0 00000000 00000000   memory near r2:
    40051fe8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
    40051ff8 00000000 00000000 00000000 0000024b  
    40052008 40ac6f50 000002d0 000004a0 3b360b61  
    40052018 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
    40052028 badd67c9 00000000 00000000 00000000  
    40052038 00000000 bf800000 00000000 bf800000  
    40052048 3f800000 80000000 3f800000 53450001  
    40052058 3f800000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
    40052068 00000000 3f800000 00000000 00000000  
    40052078 00000000 00000000 3f800000 00000000  
    40052088 00000000 00000000 00000000 3f800000  
    40052098 47200101 454f5f4c 40d4a8d0 00000000  
    400520a8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
    400520b8 00000000 00000000 00000000 3f800000  
    400520c8 00000000 3f800000 00000000 00000000  
    400520d8 3f800000 00000000 3f800000 3f800000   memory near r4:
    40051fe8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
    40051ff8 00000000 00000000 00000000 0000024b  
    40052008 40ac6f50 000002d0 000004a0 3b360b61  
    40052018 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
    40052028 badd67c9 00000000 00000000 00000000  
    40052038 00000000 bf800000 00000000 bf800000  
    40052048 3f800000 80000000 3f800000 53450001  
    40052058 3f800000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
    40052068 00000000 3f800000 00000000 00000000  
    40052078 00000000 00000000 3f800000 00000000  
    40052088 00000000 00000000 00000000 3f800000  
    40052098 47200101 454f5f4c 40d4a8d0 00000000  
    400520a8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
    400520b8 00000000 00000000 00000000 3f800000  
    400520c8 00000000 3f800000 00000000 00000000  
    400520d8 3f800000 00000000 3f800000 3f800000   memory near r7:
    40cd7a50 00000000 40cd7a84 587060b4 56d9b160  
    40cd7a60 00000006 00000000 40052008 00000000  
    40cd7a70 40cd7aa4 5870a2ca 56d9ca20 587060b4  
    40cd7a80 00000000 40052008 41749c38 00000000  
    40cd7a90 40cd7b28 5872693c 56ee96e0 5870a2ca  
    40cd7aa0 00000000 4173d8b0 4171c528 4173e720  
    40cd7ab0 41749c38 417573f8 40cd7afc 5859b240  
    40cd7ac0 56d90958 5859b20c 00000000 00000000  
    40cd7ad0 587266b2 4173dc08 00000000 4173f1c0  
    40cd7ae0 00000000 00000001 40cd7b28 4175fdf0  
    40cd7af0 00000008 00000000 40cd7b28 58726910  
    40cd7b00 4173f120 4171c528 4173e720 4173d8b0  
    40cd7b10 4173dc08 40cd7b9c 587277a8 56efd4f0  
    40cd7b20 5872693c 00000000 4173f120 4171c528  
    40cd7b30 4173d8b0 5868e060 4173dc08 4173dc48  
    40cd7b40 4173e720 00000000 00000000 4173e570   memory near r8:
    bece0650 40cd7a70 40ab5d59 00000000 40ab5d45  
    bece0660 400dd010 40252301 56d9b160 407cf294  
    bece0670 40cd7a68 00000001 40e7eab8 00000008  
    bece0680 4170d90c 407fe415 40cd7a68 5895c109  
    bece0690 402522f5 400dd020 e0e00019 00000000  
    bece06a0 5dcadae8 40193228 40de2d88 40de2d88  
    bece06b0 c0000000 40de2d88 00000000 5dcada18  
    bece06c0 00000000 40159813 40de2d88 00000000  
    bece06d0 5dcada18 00000000 40de2d88 40154f15  
    bece06e0 40de2e1c 40812cc7 bece06fc 000000c1  
    bece06f0 40e7eab8 40de2e1c 00000000 00000000  
    bece0700 bece0760 5dcad9b0 40e659a0 000000c1  
    bece0710 40e7eab8 000000c2 00000000 00000000  
    bece0720 00000000 00000000 41749c38 000000c1  
    bece0730 407d42c0 56d9b160 41749c38 40de2d88  
    bece0740 00000004 407d42c0 00000006 40cd7a54   memory near r9:
    40cd7a48 4171c988 00000000 00000000 40cd7a84  
    40cd7a58 587060b4 56d9b160 00000006 00000000  
    40cd7a68 40052008 00000000 40cd7aa4 5870a2ca  
    40cd7a78 56d9ca20 587060b4 00000000 40052008  
    40cd7a88 41749c38 00000000 40cd7b28 5872693c  
    40cd7a98 56ee96e0 5870a2ca 00000000 4173d8b0  
    40cd7aa8 4171c528 4173e720 41749c38 417573f8  
    40cd7ab8 40cd7afc 5859b240 56d90958 5859b20c  
    40cd7ac8 00000000 00000000 587266b2 4173dc08  
    40cd7ad8 00000000 4173f1c0 00000000 00000001  
    40cd7ae8 40cd7b28 4175fdf0 00000008 00000000  
    40cd7af8 40cd7b28 58726910 4173f120 4171c528  
    40cd7b08 4173e720 4173d8b0 4173dc08 40cd7b9c  
    40cd7b18 587277a8 56efd4f0 5872693c 00000000  
    40cd7b28 4173f120 4171c528 4173d8b0 5868e060  
    40cd7b38 4173dc08 4173dc48 4173e720 00000000   memory near sl:
    400dd000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000453  
    400dd010 587060b4 40cd7a68 56d9ca20 58d69000  
    400dd020 00000000 00000000 bece07a8 00000000  
    400dd030 bece07dc 00000001 00010008 407d42c0  
    400dd040 00000000 00000000 402b4570 40cd2300  
    400dd050 00000000 00000000 00000000 00006000  
    400dd060 00000000 4012f3dc 407cf400 407d42c0  
    400dd070 00000000 407d83bc 407d8430 407d82e0  
    400dd080 407d8300 407d835c 00000000 00000000  
    400dd090 00000000 00000028 00000000 00000000  
    400dd0a0 00000000 00000000 00002000 4085f8d4  
    400dd0b0 00000000 00000000 00000007 40d3e130  
    400dd0c0 00000001 00000080 00000200 00000000  
    400dd0d0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
    400dd0e0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
    400dd0f0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000   memory near fp:
    bece0664 40252301 56d9b160 407cf294 40cd7a68  
    bece0674 00000001 40e7eab8 00000008 4170d90c  
    bece0684 407fe415 40cd7a68 5895c109 402522f5  
    bece0694 400dd020 e0e00019 00000000 5dcadae8  
    bece06a4 40193228 40de2d88 40de2d88 c0000000  
    bece06b4 40de2d88 00000000 5dcada18 00000000  
    bece06c4 40159813 40de2d88 00000000 5dcada18  
    bece06d4 00000000 40de2d88 40154f15 40de2e1c  
    bece06e4 40812cc7 bece06fc 000000c1 40e7eab8  
    bece06f4 40de2e1c 00000000 00000000 bece0760  
    bece0704 5dcad9b0 40e659a0 000000c1 40e7eab8  
    bece0714 000000c2 00000000 00000000 00000000  
    bece0724 00000000 41749c38 000000c1 407d42c0  
    bece0734 56d9b160 41749c38 40de2d88 00000004  
    bece0744 407d42c0 00000006 40cd7a54 4170d90c  
    bece0754 407f466d 00000004 00000000 00001c01   memory near ip:
    402522d4 b00447a0 6811bd10 b5104610 46196a4c  
    402522e4 bd1047a0 b5086810 46106a83 bd084798  
    402522f4 46106811 6accb510 47a04619 b51fbd10  
    40252304 68119c09 f8dd980a 9401c020 46109002  
    40252314 c000f8cd 6b0c9a06 9b074619 b00447a0  
    40252324 b51fbd10 68119c09 f8dd980a 9401c020  
    40252334 46109002 c000f8cd 6b4c9a06 9b074619  
    40252344 b00447a0 b513bd10 68119c06 94009807  
    40252354 46109001 46196d0c 9b059a04 bd1c47a0  
    40252364 ee01b513 eddd3a10 eef80a04 ed9d6ac1  
    40252374 eddd0a05 68115a06 9b074610 eeb89301  
    40252384 eef87ae0 ee177ac0 eeb82a10 ee176ae5  
    40252394 ed8d3a90 6d0c6a00 1a90ee16 bd1c47a0  
    402523a4 4610b510 9a026811 46196b8c bd1047a0  
    402523b4 46106811 6bccb510 47a04619 b510bd10  
    402523c4 68114610 6c0c9a02 47a04619 b510bd10   memory near sp:
    bece0610 bece0684 407ed061 c0000000 00000000  
    bece0620 00000001 5dca4348 df0027ad 00000000  
    bece0630 00000029 00000000 40e59558 40e57ed8  
    bece0640 5d99d7b0 40052008 00000001 00000000  
    bece0650 40cd7a70 40ab5d59 00000000 40ab5d45  
    bece0660 400dd010 40252301 56d9b160 407cf294  
    bece0670 40cd7a68 00000001 40e7eab8 00000008  
    bece0680 4170d90c 407fe415 40cd7a68 5895c109  
    bece0690 402522f5 400dd020 e0e00019 00000000  
    bece06a0 5dcadae8 40193228 40de2d88 40de2d88  
    bece06b0 c0000000 40de2d88 00000000 5dcada18  
    bece06c0 00000000 40159813 40de2d88 00000000  
    bece06d0 5dcada18 00000000 40de2d88 40154f15  
    bece06e0 40de2e1c 40812cc7 bece06fc 000000c1  
    bece06f0 40e7eab8 40de2e1c 00000000 00000000  
    bece0700 bece0760 5dcad9b0 40e659a0 000000c1   code around pc:
    40ab5c5c f7f60008 4620fd76 4010e8bd bb92f00a  
    40ab5c6c 4601bd10 b085b5f0 3f9cf851 46684604  
    40ab5c7c f7f8685f f8d4fa51 a801109c 0501f007  
    40ab5c8c 0602f007 f7f83108 0739fa47 9f01d520  
    40ab5c9c 3a06ed97 2a07ed97 2ac3eefd 1a08ed97  
    40ab5cac 0a09ed97 1ac2eefd 0a90ee12 0ac1eefd  
    40ab5cbc 1a90ee11 7ac0eefd 2a90ee10 3a90ee17  
    40ab5ccc efa2f7ef f1049900 312c000c ff12f7f9  
    40ab5cdc 1094f8d4 1e489f01 0094f8c4 4638b117  
    40ab5cec ee1ef7ef 009cf8d4 f7ffb108 f8c4ffa5  
    40ab5cfc b115709c f8842201 b1a621dc 46696826  
    40ab5d0c f8d6a802 f7f860d0 a901fa07 f7f8a803  
    40ab5d1c 4620fa03 aa03a902 a80347b0 fd11f7f6  
    40ab5d2c f7f6a802 a801fd0e fd0bf7f6 f7f64668  
    40ab5d3c 4628fd08 bdf0b005 460db538 2d014604  
    40ab5d4c 2501bfb8 4620e002 ff8bf7ff 3094f8d4   code around lr:
    40ab5d38 f7f64668 4628fd08 bdf0b005 460db538  
    40ab5d48 2d014604 2501bfb8 4620e002 ff8bf7ff  
    40ab5d58 3094f8d4 dcf842ab f8d0bd38 2b013094  
    40ab5d68 f7ffdd01 4770bf80 4604b570 b0a86800  
    40ab5d78 91014616 46206981 46204788 f7fb9901  
    40ab5d88 f8d4f80b f7f30158 f894fb04 b11331dc  
    40ab5d98 f7fb4620 f8d4fd75 6f69509c c90fad05  
    40ab5da8 000fe885 f7fa4628 6823fd70 f8d34620  
    40ab5db8 479020d8 6820b148 20d4f8d0 47904620  
    40ab5dc8 46024629 f7fb4620 edddfcdc eddd4a05  
    40ab5dd8 eebd3a06 eddd4ae4 eddd2a07 68211a08  
    40ab5de8 f8d14620 eebd50d8 ed8d3ae3 eebd4a0d  
    40ab5df8 ed8d2ae2 eebd3a0e ed8d1ae1 ed8d2a0f  
    40ab5e08 47a81a10 059cf104 f88d4629 a802004c  
    40ab5e18 f984f7f8 ed909802 edd07a08 ee370a06  
    40ab5e28 a8020a60 7ac0eefd 7a11edcd fc8bf7f6
    I/BootReceiver(390): Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_09 to DropBox(SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)
    I/ActivityManager(390): Process com.cappucino.android.widgets (pid 20514) has died.
    I/WindowState(390): WIN DEATH: Window{42bcd680 u0 com.cappucino.android.widgets/com.cappucino.android.widgets.MainActivity}
    W/ActivityManager(390): Force removing ActivityRecord{41b32568 u0 com.cappucino.android.widgets/.MainActivity}: app died, no saved state
```

I am very sorry for the incredibly long backtrace, but this is how it is. After I get all that in the logcat the application closes. Most of the stuff is printed in the general log filter not the application specific.

When I comment out the line: `listRowView.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);` the app starts ok but I do not get the result I want.

Any suggestions how I can fix the problem? Any ideas what the problem actually is?

**EDIT**

It seems the problem is somewhere around the fact that the canvas of the list view element is not completely initialized when the `getView` method is called. How do I call a method afer the canvas has been initialized (this must be after he `ListView` cell is rendered).

**EDIT 2**

The row layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <!-- ListRow Left side Thumbnail image -->

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:id="@+id/inner_layout">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:padding="3dip" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/thumbnail_image"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:background="@android:color/black"
                android:contentDescription="@string/image_thumb_desc"
                android:padding="1dp"
                android:src="@drawable/default_thumb" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <!-- Title Of Book -->

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/thumbnail"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:textSize="15dip"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="sans" />

        <!-- Author Name -->

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/author"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/title"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:textSize="10dip" />

        <!-- Arrow -->

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/arrow" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: are you sure the problem is not related to the drawable itself?

Comment: @blackbelt: Thank you! Finally a response! Yes, I think so becaue that works with ordinary view (e.g. `TextView`) and also I have added `onClick` of the `ListView` elements and through it I am able to change the bckground. I think th eprobem is that the drawable uses the view canvas, obviously, and the canvas is not ready to use at this stage.

Comment: ok.. I am clueless. I disagree with you. How does slide_layout_row.xml composed?

Comment: @blackbelt posted in the question.

Comment: can you try to use the dafault launcher icon (the default android icon) and see if it makes any difference?

Comment: @blackbelt: instead of the launcher icon of my app you mean?

Comment: yes, can you try the default icon for all the element of your listview?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29590/discussion-between-boris-strandjev-and-blackbelt)

Comment: we tracked it down :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It seems the problem is somewhere around the fact that the canvas of
>   the list view element is not completely initialized when the getView
>   method is called. How do I call a method afer the canvas has been
>   initialized (this must be after he ListView cell is rendered).

Not It's not . The problem is surely related with your custom class `BackgroundDrawable`.

**EDIT (boris strandjev \ OP).** More specifically the problem was a division by zero I did in the `draw` of the drawable