# Call method when list view element is visualized

Tags: android, android-listview, listener

This question is the final bit I need to sort out this other [question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16424835/sigsegv-when-setting-backgrounddrawable-for-each-element-in-listview) (I am linking so that I justify why I need what I ask for).

Is there a way to invoke a method when a specific `ListView` element is visualized on the screen? I need actual visualization and, as is obvious from the linked question, the method I need must come in the invocation chain after `getView` of the `ListViewAdapter`, when the dimensions of the new view are already determined.

Comment: What does visualized on the screen means? A height of 1 pixel from that view visible on the screen it makes the view visualized?

Comment: @Luksprog: What I need is to have the `view.getHeight()` being different from 0 for the list view element. I am not exactly certain when that happens but it seems to be after the call to `getView`.

Comment: You could at first(after `onCreate()`) see if the target view is in the rows currently on the screen with also watching the scroll of the `ListView` to see if the view appears/disappears from the screen.

Comment: @Luksprog Thank you for your suggestion. Still it is a bit too vague fo rme to be able to implement your idea. Do you mind giving me a bit more details?

Comment: My comment above is not quite right especially in the context of your other question. See if you can't implement the logic directly in a custom view instead of needing to know when the row is visible.